# CraftCMS upgrade issue from 3 to 4

Tags: php, yii2, craftcms

I'm trying to upgrade CraftCMS 3 to 4 version successfully completed until database migration step,
When i try to run `php craft migrate/all` command getting the bellow migration error,

[image]

columnSuffix column is currently missing in the fields table (before the migration run)

I really appreciate if i get a generous help from the community team to solve this issue.

Comment: I found a solution with the help of the support team, so the issue was i was trying to upgrade 3.5v directly to 4.00v, but the correct way is upgrade to 3.9v first and then upgrade to the 4.0v. Issue solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the help of the support team, so the issue was i was trying to upgrade 3.5v directly to 4.00v, but the correct way is upgrade to 3.9v first and then upgrade to the 4.0v. Issue solved.